# Windows azure staging tfs built error in visual studio 2012 in windows 8

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have created a project as a cloud service in windows azure and trying to deploy staging server using tfs in visual studio 2012 in windows 8.

I have installed latest Windows Azure SDK too.

I got following error and built fails.

```
Exception Message: There was no Windows Azure project (.ccproj) detected in the solution. Continuous delivery to an Azure Cloud Service requires an Azure project. (type CCProjNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

My azure SQL server gets connected to project and works fine locally.

I google the problem a lot but didn't able to solve my problem.

I appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Its my bad. I created MVC 4 project instead of making windows azure cloud service.